# How to access a variable defined inside a function from out side?

Tags: python

Let us consider the following program

```
def fib(n): 
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)    
        a, b = b, a+b
        c = result
    print c
return result

f100 = fib(100)
print result
#print c
```

How can I access the variable 'c' from out side the function? Is it possible? I know

```
print result
```

will give the same, but i want to know is there any method to access 'c' outside the function?

Comment: Why would you want to access `c`, when the value is already returned and stored in variable `f100`? And is the indentation for `return result` correct? And generally if you want to access something inside a function, you need to use either "global variable" or "return the value"

Comment: that's imporssible, there is no `c` nor its value outside your function

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-17/python-scope-basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare c as global, although that's not generally a pattern you'd want to encourage. You'd do that like this:

```
c = None

def fib(n):
    global c

    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)    
        a, b = b, a+b
        c = result
    return result

f100 = fib(100)
print result
print c
```

You could also restructure your function as a class with a `__call__` method which would let you expose internal values as attributes, such as:

```
class fibber(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = None

    def __call__(self, n):
        result = []
        a, b = 0, 1
        while b < n:
            result.append(b)    
            a, b = b, a+b
            self.c = result
        return result

fib = fibber()
f100 = fib(100)
print result
print fib.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Local variables only exist in the context of the function they are defined in.  That's what makes them local.  So the whole variable `c` does not exist anymore once the function terminates and returns its result value.

You can of course save the value of that variable in a different one, e. g. a field of the function itself:

```
fib.c = c
```

Since the function itself will exist also after it terminated, so will its fields, and so will `fib.c`.

But I must stress that this is just a hack.  Normally if you want to access a value outside of a function it is a good idea to make the variable holding that value not local.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare c a global variable:

```
def fib(n): 
    global c
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)    
        a, b = b, a+b
        c = result
    print c
    return result

result = fib(10)
print result
print c
```